# Vim: How to exclude file types from autocmd?

Tags: vim, file-type

I want markdown files to ignore the below snippet. How could I do this?

```
" highlight ugly code
augroup HighlightUglyCode
    autocmd!
    autocmd WinEnter,BufEnter * call clearmatches() | call matchadd('ErrorMsg', '\s\+$', 100) | call matchadd('ErrorMsg', '\%>150v.\+', 100)
augroup EN
```

I tried doing

```
autocmd FileType md
```

But from my understanding that would target .md files, not exclude them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You could do something like:

```
autocmd WinEnter,BufEnter * if &ft != "md" | do things
```